# Calling obj_id in html using django

Tags: html, django

why is it i can update the **College** record but when i tried to update for example **Grade 1** it didnt update. when i tried to print the **id = request.POST.get('id')
    print("id", id)** i always get **("id", 14)**

How do i fix my html?

I have this code in my html

```
<form  method="post" action="/UpdateEducationLevel/" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{% for gradelevel in gradelevels %}
<tr>
<td  class="tdcell"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{gradelevel.id}}">{{gradelevel.id}}</td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell"><input type="text" value="{{gradelevel.Description}}" name="gradelevel"></td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell">
    <select name="status">
        <option>{{gradelevel.Status}}</option>
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <h3>
                <button class="save">&plus;&nbsp;Update</button>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </td> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

this is what its looks ln web view

[image]
this is my logic on updating what i selecting data to update

```
def UpdateEducationLevel(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    print("id", id)
    desc = request.POST.get('gradelevel')
    status = request.POST.get('status')
    update = EducationLevel.objects.get(id=id)
    update.Description=desc
    update.Status = status
    update.save()
```

Comment: Can you add the code that submits the update request to the server? Like a form or a ajax perhaps?

Comment: i dont have ajax

Comment: Alright, but how are you sending yout update to the server? Can you share it?

Comment: i update my question

Comment: I have "" form action="/UpdateEducationLevel/" ""

Comment: You're trying to make multiple updates altogether or just one at a time is enough?

Comment: just one at a time sir,

Comment: when i tried to update the College to College1 it works fine, but when i tried to update grade 1, it didnt update, i tried to print the id and i always get id=14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215133/discussion-between-justin-and-bernardo-duarte).

Comment: You're probably always submitting the same form if you're seeing the same id in that view. Also, the template code suggest that you should have an update button in every row and your page screenshot has a single Update button. Maybe tell everyone what you're trying to do...

Comment: @somecallitblues , I see i will try to add update button for every row

Comment: I've added an answer, can you see if it works? It is just prototype, I believe you'll want to tweak it to your desires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is due to having a single form for multiple inputs with the same name, therefore making one overwrite the other when submitting, hence always the same id.

I believe you should add the update button once per row, that way you can make a form per `gradelevel` and when submitting you will get the id of the row you're updating.

```
{% for gradelevel in gradelevels %}
<form  method="post" action="/UpdateEducationLevel/" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<tr>
<td  class="tdcell"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{gradelevel.id}}">{{gradelevel.id}}</td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell"><input type="text" value="{{gradelevel.Description}}" name="gradelevel"></td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell">
    <select name="status">
        <option>{{gradelevel.Status}}</option>
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <button class="save">&plus;&nbsp;Update</button>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: its still the same :(